# NSIS - File /x doesn't exclude files/directories as claimed

Tags: directory, nsis

I have a directory structure that needs to be added to the installer. I have 3 different versions of my install script, and one of them being an upgrade script, requires excluding a certain file and a subdirectory within my install directory.
So I do the following:

```
File /r  /x ${InputDir}\data\someFile.xml /x ${InputDir}\data\derbydb\runtime\*.* ${InputDir}\*.*
```

The xml file and the derbydb directory are already present (since this is an upgrade) and hence I don't want to overwrite them. Yet on running the installer I clearly see that both files are overwritten, and moreover viewing the generated setup.exe with 7zip shows that they got added as well. One may as well have just called

```
File /r ${InputDir}\*.*
```

So what's going wrong here? I wish NSIS would have better documentation or list caveats with 
their command parameters/syntax. (/rant)

Answer (score 9):

NSIS manual (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html) section **4.9.1.5 File** contains the following:

> Use the /x switch to exclude files or directories.

I tried to use different variants, but only one worked:

```
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
File /r /x Config ..\MyProgram\*.*
```

where "Config" is a directory "MyProgram\Plugins\Config".
NSIS searches only by name and it will be wrong to set any subfolders (e.g. "/x Plugins\Config" or "/x $INSTDIR\MyProgram\Plugins\Config\"). There is one lack: if you have the same folders in different directories, using the /r switch, both matching directories and files will be searched.

Answer (score 3):

I find that

```
File /x "${DIRECTORY}Foo.img" "${DIRECTORY}*.img"
```

does NOT exclude Foo.img at compilation time - it is included with the other .img files.

Answer (score 3):

Finally cracked it after pulling some of my hair out...

First exclude the whole sub directory from the `*.*`

```
File /r /x "subfolder" "C:\App\bin\*.*"
```

then change your output directory in to your subfolder...

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\subfolder"
```

then exclude the xml files...

```
File /r /x "*.xml" "C:\App\bin\subfolder\*.*"
```

and then set the output path back to how it was...

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
```

so it should look somthing like this...

```
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
File /r /x "subfolder" "C:\App\bin\*.*"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\subfolder"
File /r /x "*.xml" "C:\App\bin\subfolder\*.*"
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
```

Comment: Wish I could mark this as the answer, but I haven't worked again on NSIS since then so can't confirm.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you shouldn't be specifying the full path to the files to exclude just a pattern, so in other words the command should look like this:

```
File /r  /x data\someFile.xml /x data\derbydb\runtime\*.* ${InputDir}\*.*
```

Comment: I've already tried this and it doesn't work. It still includes the xml file inside the installer, and overwrites what's already there.

Answer (score 2):

The `/x` is for excluding some files to be included in the installer *at compile time*.

If I understand correctly, you want to avoid the overwriting of files during the installation / upgrade *at run time*.

Thus you could use the `SetOverwrite` compiler flag before the `File` directive. Look at the manual section [**4.8.2.8 SetOverwrite**](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.2.8), the section [4.8.2](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.2) also shows a method to handle `SetOverwrite` dynamically.

Comment: But the point is that it doesn't exclude them even at compile time. If I open the generated setup file I can see that it contains the files I wanted to exclude.

Comment: @Rex: Well, the documentation does not seem to state explicitly that directory paths are supported for `/x` as they are for `/r`... It says : `/x file|wildcard`

Comment: But it doesn't work even for files, whether you use a wildcard or provide an exact path.

Comment: @Rex: The problem is something else, because I do use `/x` in my own installers, e.g. `File /nonfatal /r /x .svn /x *.pl "${InstSrcFiles}\excel"` (in this case .svn is a folder and *.pl are files). Are you sure that the `${InputDir}` is correct ?

Comment: I suppose it is, because it's able to process ${INPUTDIR}\*.* correctly. I've also tried not specifying input dir in the /x, i.e. just using data\file.xml, or data\*.xml and neither work.

Comment: @Rex: I notice that I am adding a whole dir byt its name and without specifying `*.*`. Matybe that it is your caveat ? I will try to look at NSIS source to see if `*.*` is not overwritting the `/x` parameter. I agree with you that the NSIS documentation is perfectible :p

Answer (score 1):

```
var pname
!define pname "Salt v1.2.9.3c"
File /r /x small-games.info.url "E:\Games\${pname}\*.*"
```

include **E:\Games\${pname}*.***, but exclude **small-games.info.url** in folders

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me there's a bug which is that if you do:

```
File /r "C:\folder a\subfolder b"
File /r /x "subfolder b" "C:\folder b"
```

then `C:\folder b\subfolder a\subfolder b` will still get copied as part of the first operation.

Answer (score 0):

working example for files =   File /r /x *.*jpg D:\Desktop\NSIS\Examples\wp_test_build*.*

working example for folders =   File /r /x Config D:\Desktop\NSIS\Examples\wp_test_build*.*

Answer (score 0):

When the folder to be excluded is a sub-folder, just use the form "File /r /x subFolderName", where the subFolderName should be the name of the subfolder itself, not containing any name of the parent folders from "$INSTDIR".